# How to get the actual forecasts from ets function?

Tags: r, ets

Suppose I'm using the `ets` function from the `forecast` package in R and I've fit the model to a single time series `t` with something like

```
ets_model = ets(t)
fcast = forecast(ets_model, h=1)
```

I can see the forecast if I type `fcast` in the console, but how do I actually *extract* this value so I can use it as part of a program?  I've been searching through the contents of `str(fcast)` and can't find the actual forecast anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `fcast$mean`:

```
fcast <- forecast(ets(rnorm(20)), h = 1)
fcast
#    Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
# 21    -0.06945796 -0.9153854 0.7764694 -1.363192 1.224276
fcast$mean
# Time Series:
# Start = 21 
# End = 21 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] -0.06945796
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Do you know by chance which value gets used as the standard error to construct prediction intervals?  I thought it may have been fcast$model$sigma2, but this value appears to be way too small in some situations.

Comment: Ok, looks like it might be fcast$model$mse?

Comment: @dsaxton, looking at `forecast.ets` it seems that either `$model$sigma2` or bootstrap is used